# Using TArray class functions

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe7, generic-collections

I need to sort a `TArray<integer>`, I've added `System.Generics.Collections` to the `uses` clause and then I've tried the following code:

```
var
  Arr : TArray<integer>;
begin
  SetLength(Arr, 2);
  Arr[0] := 5;
  Arr[1] := 3;

  TArray.Sort(Arr);

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Arr[0]));
end;
```

On compiling it produces an *E2250* error saying:

> [dcc32 Error] Unit1.pas(39): E2250 There is no overloaded version of
>   'Sort' that can be called with these arguments

Answer (score 3):

While writing the question I've found the answer... (It was a trivial syntax problem)

In `TArray` class, the `Sort` function is defined as follows:

```
class procedure Sort<T>(var Values: array of T); overload; static;
```

So `TArray` class functions must be called by specifying the type **after** the function name:

```
var
  Arr : TArray<integer>;
begin
  SetLength(Arr, 2);
  Arr[0] := 5;
  Arr[1] := 3;

  TArray.Sort<integer>(Arr);

  ShowMessage(IntToStr(Arr[0]));
end;
```

Comment: A decent compiler would be able to infer the type. Delphi generics though, meh.